# Error HH411: The library openzeppelin, imported from contracts/Project.sol, is not installed

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens, openzeppelin

I keep getting the OpenZeppelin `ERROR HH411` when I try to run `npx hardhat test`,
noting that I already installed all libraries and checked them in my project local folder.
I am using solidity version ^0.8.0.

I've tried every single solution on the internet.

Appreciate any help I can get, and please let me know what can I provide more so you guys can help me.

Comment: How are you importing OpenZeppelin files? What's the configuration like? Do you have a github repo with the project?

Comment: @tony_1611 I got the same error here, have you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you use the version number in the import statement then you get this error.  e.g.

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.3/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
```

Then you get the ERROR HH411 even though the library is installed.  When I removed the version reference then it sorted itself out.  e.g.

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
```

This threw me because I started the work on the contract on Remix where this was not an issue.
I hope that that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did  `yarn add @openzeppelin/contracts`  and it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

First poster here. I've had a similar issue, my solidity imports were not working until I uninstalled the Solidity Extension by Juan Blanco and installed the Solidity extension by the Nomic Foundation.

**Uninstall this:**
[image]

Hope this helps.

Cheers!